# Multisite domain path access control

Tags: multi-sites, domain-access

E.g. My site have two subdomains : domain_a and domain_b.

I create a path: "custom/a".

I hope:

domain_a can visit the path.

domain_b visit the path, get 404.

Except according to the `golbal $domain` in the code, does anyone have other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do that, but an easy one is to use the [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module to define the page, coupled with [domain_ctools](https://drupal.org/project/domain_ctools)

Then you can just add a selection rule or access control rule to specify the valid domains via the user interface.

Alternatively, you could do something with [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/hook_menu) access callbacks.

Comment: Thank for your fast reply. <br/> I just found a way use [contex](https://drupal.org/project/context) + [domaincontext](https://drupal.org/project/domaincontext. And I will also try your idea. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me!  Thank for your idea.  However, I still have a little problem with it.  When the domain(not allowed visit) visit the page got "Access denied".  I hope to show "Not found" or custom content.  Do you have any good idea ?

Comment: Add another "variant" to the page to match the other domain. You can also add an "http response code" variant for a 404 response.